# Segmentation fault while writing to outputfile

Tags: c++, file-io, segmentation-fault

In the following program, I am writing some data into a file named "griddata.dat". I am getting a segmentation fault during the function

> write_grid_file

The function is partly executed. After running the programming, the last line of the file griddata.dat is "The thresholds are as follows. A threshold of 0 means that no houses are located at that point."

The number of characters/lines/bytes of this file is dependent of the input by the user in earlier executed functions.

Code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <random>  // int_distribution
# include <cmath>   // sqrt
# include <algorithm>   // max function
# include <vector>

using namespace std ;


void make_grid(int& width, int& height, int& length, int& steps){}

void assign_noise_levels_to_aircrafts(int& nr_of_aircrafts, double& max_noise_level, double& min_noise_level, vector<double>& noise_level){}

double dist(int point_1[2], int point_2[2], int steps){}

double noise_pollution_at_point(int aircraft, int point[2], vector<double> noise_level, int steps, int runway_ending_left, int grid_width, int grid_mid_height){}

void calculate_noise_pollution(int nr_of_aircrafts, int grid_height, int grid_width, int grid_mid_height, int steps, int runway_ending_left, vector<vector<vector<double>>>& noise_pollution, vector<double> noise_level){}

void put_houses(int runway_ending_left, int runway_ending_right, int grid_mid_height, int grid_height, int grid_width, vector<vector<int>>& nr_of_houses){}

int count_housing_locations(vector<vector<int>> nr_of_houses, int grid_height, int grid_width){}

void complete_data (int grid_height, int grid_width, int& min_nr_of_flights, double& const_threshold, vector<vector<int>> nr_of_houses, vector<vector<double>> threshold)
{
    cout << "Enter the threshold value of noise pollution at each housing location: " ;
    cin >> const_threshold ;

    for (int i=0 ; i < grid_height ; i++)
    {
        vector<double> row ;
        for (int j=0 ; j < grid_width ; j++)
        {
            if(nr_of_houses[i][j]==0)
                row.push_back(0) ;
            else
                row.push_back(const_threshold) ;
        }
    threshold.push_back(row) ;
    }
    cout << "Enter the number of flights that should at least be scheduled: " ;
    cin >> min_nr_of_flights ;
}

void write_grid_file (int width, int height, int length, int steps, int grid_height, int grid_width, int grid_mid_height, int grid_mid_width, int runway_ending_left, int runway_ending_right, int nr_of_aircrafts, int min_nr_of_flights, vector<double> noise_level, vector<vector<vector<double>>> noise_pollution, vector<vector<int>> nr_of_houses, vector<vector<double>> threshold)
{
    ofstream gridfile ;
    gridfile.open ("griddata.dat") ;

    gridfile << "Width of the grid is " << width << "km.\n"
         << "Height of the grid is " << height << "km.\n"
         << "Length of the runway is " << length << "km.\n"
         << "There are " << steps << " measure points per km. \n\n"
         << "Therefore, the grid is a matrix with " << grid_height << " rows and " << grid_width << " columns.\n"
         << "The midpoint of the grid is [" << grid_mid_height << "," << grid_mid_width << "].\n"
         << "The runway ranges from [" << grid_mid_height << "," << runway_ending_left << "] to [" << grid_mid_height << "," << runway_ending_right <<"].\n\n" ;

    for(int i=0 ; i < nr_of_aircrafts ; i++)
        gridfile << "The noise level of aircraft " << i+1 << " is " << noise_level[i] << endl ;
    gridfile << endl ;

    for(int aircraft=0 ; aircraft < nr_of_aircrafts ; aircraft++)
    {
        gridfile << "The noise pollution of aircraft " << aircraft+1 << " is given by:" << endl ;
        for(int i=0 ; i < grid_height ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j < grid_width ; j++)
                gridfile << noise_pollution[aircraft][i][j] << "    " ;
            gridfile << endl ;
        }
        gridfile << endl ;
    }
    gridfile << endl ;

    gridfile << "The houses are located as follows:" << endl ;
    for(int i=0 ; i < grid_height ; i++)
    {   for(int j=0 ; j < grid_width ; j++)
            gridfile << nr_of_houses[i][j] << " " ;
        gridfile << endl ;
    }
    gridfile << endl ;

    gridfile << "The number of housing locations is " << count_housing_locations(nr_of_houses, grid_height, grid_width)
         << endl << endl ;

    gridfile << "The thresholds are as follows. A threshold of 0 means that no houses are located at that point. " << endl << endl ;
// segmentation fault here
    for(int i=0 ; i < grid_height ; i++)
    {   for(int j=0 ; j < grid_width ; j++)
            gridfile << threshold[i][j] << "    " ;
        gridfile << endl ;
    }
    gridfile << endl << endl
         << "The number of flights that must at least be scheduled is " << min_nr_of_flights << endl ;

    gridfile.close() ;
}

void write_scip_file (int grid_height, int grid_width, int nr_of_aircrafts, int min_nr_of_flights, vector<vector<int>> nr_of_houses, vector<vector<double>> threshold, vector<vector<vector<double>>> noise_pollution){}


int main()
{
// design the grid
    int steps ;
    int width ;
    int height ;
    int length ;

    make_grid(width, height, length, steps) ;

// define aircrafts by calculating their noise levels
    int nr_of_aircrafts ;
    double max_noise_level ;
    double min_noise_level ;
    vector<double> noise_level ;

    assign_noise_levels_to_aircrafts(nr_of_aircrafts, max_noise_level, min_noise_level, noise_level) ;

// calculate noise pollution for every aircraft
    int grid_width = (width*steps) + 1 ;
    int grid_height = (height*steps) + 1 ;

    int grid_mid_width = 0.5*width*steps ;
    int grid_mid_height = 0.5*height*steps ;
    int runway_ending_left = grid_mid_width - 0.5*length*steps ;
    int runway_ending_right = grid_mid_width + 0.5*length*steps ;

    vector<vector<vector<double>>> noise_pollution ;

    calculate_noise_pollution(nr_of_aircrafts, grid_height, grid_width, grid_mid_height, steps, runway_ending_left, noise_pollution, noise_level) ;

// put one house on the grid points at random
    vector<vector<int>> nr_of_houses ;

    put_houses(runway_ending_left, runway_ending_right, grid_mid_height, grid_height, grid_width, nr_of_houses) ;

// completing the data (b,k)
    vector<vector<double>> threshold ;
    double const_threshold ;
    int min_nr_of_flights ;

    complete_data (grid_height, grid_width, min_nr_of_flights, const_threshold, nr_of_houses, threshold) ;

// write data into two files, one for people, one for scip
    write_grid_file(width, height, length, steps, grid_height, grid_width, grid_mid_height, grid_mid_width, runway_ending_left, runway_ending_right, nr_of_aircrafts, min_nr_of_flights, noise_level, noise_pollution, nr_of_houses, threshold) ;

    write_scip_file (grid_height, grid_width, nr_of_aircrafts, min_nr_of_flights, nr_of_houses, threshold, noise_pollution) ;

// test if the whole program is run
    cout << endl << "Done!" << endl << endl ;

 return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a *minimal* example that shows the problem

Answer (score 1):

`complete_data` takes `threshold` by value, so it does not modify main's `threshold`. But then `write_grid_file` uses the `[]` operator to index into this empty vector, causing undefined behaviour. (There may also be other errors, this one just stood out to me by reading your code).

First of all, redesign your code so that when you iterate over a vector, you actually iterate over the vector using its `size` property or its own begin/end iterators. Don't use `grid_height` as a dimension for this other vector.

Also, if there is any doubt whatsoever about your indices, use `.at()` instead of `[]` so that you can throw an exception on failure

Your code is very difficult to follow because of the large number of function parameters. Instead you should be using object-oriented design. Make your grid be represented by a class , and then your functions will only need to take one object of that class as parameter, with perhaps one or two other parameters.

Finally, learn to use your debugger to see where segfaults are coming from.

Comment: The call by value wasn't the only problem, but thanks for this useful comment. I have solved it now (I think), there was a problem in another function. You are right that the code is difficult to read because of the parameters. I don't know about these classes, but I will certainly have a look at those. Thanks for the tip.